# Blade link to script

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Wondering how can I link with blade syntax to my jquery/javascript files?

```
 <script src="../../public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <script src="../../public/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This didn't work:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('js/jquery.min.js') }}"> 

 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('js/bootstrap.js') }}">
```

Comment: Is your file named `x.blade.php`?

Comment: In your last code example you are loading JavaScript with a CSS link, type and rel. That will not work. I posted an answer that will work for sure. This will also work when your creating packages in the workbench. It's the correct way of loading assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL::to($param)` directs to your root folder (/public) and adds the string folders. `URL::to('js/bootstrap.js')` directs to `/public/js/bootstrap.js`. this looks correct to me.

although you used a css linking tag for javascript. try using:

```
<script src="{{ URL::to('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::to('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I was curious and looked up the main difference between URL::to vs URL::asset, mentioned by @sidneydobber. blooged here https://medium.com/p/fd427ed6f7ef. spoiler alert: you get more utility by using to() over asset().

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"><script/>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/js/bootstrap.js') }}"><script/>
```

This will always work. If you are creating a package in workbench this is also the way to go.

And if you want to publish your assets to public you will do:

```
php artisan asset:publish --bench="vendor/package"
```